# Ethernaut Challenge: Gatekeeper One

Tags: solidity

Trying to pass the second gate, but I don't understand why Remix throws the following error when I am trying to execute the function: *Gas estimation failed
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted*

This is my code.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IGatekeeperOne {
  function enter(bytes8 _gateKey) external returns (bool);
}
contract Building  {
  IGatekeeperOne gatekeeperOne = IGatekeeperOne(0x6AdE211c87Fe3E6C1e074EFbf7C0a58BDDCbdEB1);
  event Failed(bytes reason, uint256 gas);
  function attack() public {
    uint256 initialGas = 80000;
      gatekeeperOne.enter{gas: initialGas}('0x001');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you would be failing on the gateTwo's require.

The gas needs to be a multiple of 8191 by the time it gets to gateTwo()

Comment: Also do you know why I can't find an OPCODE GAS when I click on debug in remix after I initiate the function.

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not sure about it. Try doing your tests with Foundry, it's a great smart contracts development framework and is a lot more powerful than remix. You can run your tests with `forge test -vvvvv` to print out every details about your tx and why it fails. Look here https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/tests. Alos, if my answer helped, don't forget to give an upvote, that helps me. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. If you have time could you please check my question about Shop Challenge.